# Unlinked web pages on a server - security hole?

Tags: html, security

On my website, I have several html files I do not link off the main portal page. Without other people linking to them, is it possible for Jimmy Evil Hacker to find them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If anyone accesses the pages with advanced options turned on on their Google toolbar, then the address will be sent to Google. This is the only reason I have can figure out why some pages I have are on Google.

So, the answer is yes. Ensure you have a robots.txt or even .htaccess or something.

Comment: Well it would be useful if you are in their position if you want to know about every page on the Internet. (Plus it's in the disclaimer.)

Comment: The problem with a robots.txt is that someone looking for holes in your obscurity-security system will likely check there first.

Comment: @Frank Schmitt: this is very true. So the best is to put some other kind of blockage on it, such as password.

Answer (score 3):

Hidden pages are **REALLY** hard to find.

First, be absolutely sure that your web server does not return any default index pages ever.  Use the following everywhere in your configuration and `.htaccess` files.  There's probably something similar for IIS.

```
Options -Indexes
```

Second, make sure the file name isn't a dictionary word -- the odds of guessing a non-dictionary word fall to astronomically small.  Non-zero, there's a theoretical possibility that someone, somewhere might patiently guess every possible file name until they find yours.  [I hate these theoretical attacks.  Yes, they exist.  No, they'll never happen in your lifetime, unless you've given someone a reason to search for your hidden content.]

Answer (score 2):

Your talking about security through obscurity (google it) and it's never a good idea to rely on it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is.

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely they will be found, but still a possibility.

[The term "security through obscurity" comes to mind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)